# Can we use same Crashlytics app for iphone and mac application

Tags: ios, macos, crashlytics

Hi I have developed one application for both iOS and OSX. I have two targets in my application settings. Now I have implemented crashlytics for iOS app. Can I use same  crashlytics for OSX and If YES then how? Can you please give me a steps to implement in both the apps.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here.

While [this document](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/tvos.html#install-in-dual-ios-and-tvos-target-projects) covers tvOS and not macOS, it will accomplish the same goal.

1) Use Fabric.app to follow the standard installation steps for Crashlytics into your iOS target.

2) To prevent the Crashlytics and Fabric iOS frameworks from being overwritten when onboarding your macOS target move both frameworks to a new location.

3) Update the Framework Search Paths in your iOS project’s Build Settings.

4) Update the /run path in your iOS Run Scipt Build Phase to point to the updated location.

5) Build your iOS project to ensure the frameworks and /run script are detected.

6) Switch to your macOS project’s scheme.

7) Use Fabric.app to follow the standard installation steps for Crashlytics into your macOS target.

8) Follow the steps above to move the frameworks, update the Framework Search Paths, and edit the run script build phase for your macOS target.